# Laravel Artisan access denied for root@localhost on console only

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I have a problem with Laravel. My website has no problem accessing and performing operations on the database but when I try to run

`php artisan migrate`

On a terminal I get the error:

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>   SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
>   (using pas     sword: NO) (SQL: select * from
>   information_schema.tables where table_schema      = test and
>   table_name = migrations)
>
> [PDOException]
>   SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
>   (using pas     sword: NO)

I have read every thread on the Internet about this error that I could find and none of them answered my question. It was always because people did not enter their database information correctly... However that is not my case since everything works fine in browser, I just cannot perform database related operations via the console like migrating or creating new database entries via `artisan tinker`.

Here is what my config/database.php file:

```
'connections' => [
    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'test'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
]
```

And my .env config:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=test
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

I am stuck on figuring this problem out, so I appreciate your help a lot. I'm running XAMPP on my local machine and its on macOS 10.1.

Comment: better create additional user for this, with password.

Comment: @BagusTesa I tried, It didn't work.

Comment: hmm, thats weird, ever tried to open the mysql (mariadb) yourself..? using the `mysql` command line.. its in the XAMPP's directory..

Comment: @BagusTesa Yes and it opens without problems.

Comment: hmm, thats weird, i can't think of anything else..

Comment: @BagusTesa I posted an answer. `mysql` needed to be globally available for the console to work. In this instance I was using absolute path `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc..` to run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are still having this problem.

Laravel command lines depend on the command `mysql` being accessible globally. Mine was not, I was using the absolute path to link to it because I am using XAMPP.

I corrected this issue by making the `mysql` command available globally. With a XAMPP installation in Mac just run this command in your terminal:

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Applications/xampp/xamppfiles/bin:$PATH
```

This should make `mysql` globally available and fix your migration problems.

Comment: I am having the same problem, and attempted this fix on Windows.  Unfortunately, it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Root is username for system administrator for linux and Mac base Os. "php artisan" command is not set to run under 'root' user. Try to run under non administrator(non root) user

Comment: I thought this is what could be the problem so I tried creating another user with a password (and all privileges) but I still got the same error.

Comment: Changing root to something else fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I've just set the DB_PASSWORD and it worked!

Like this:

```
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1

DB_PORT=3306

DB_DATABASE=bacon

DB_USERNAME=root

DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem for me was that the password contained special characters, and so had to be quoted in the .env file:

```
DB_USERNAME={user}
DB_PASSWORD="{password}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed the following steps and I was able to overcome this issue-

1. Created another user in mysql other than root.
2. Grant all on *.* to 'newuser'@'localhost'
3. Changed the user in .env file
4. Made the mysql exe file location as a value in the PATH system variable in windows
5. Restarted the system
6. Restarted the wamp development server
7. php artisan cache:clear
8. php artisan config:cache
9. Now the next thing to check was the mysql port
10. Enter via terminal to mysql:

mysql -u root -p
and then type the following in the mysql prompt:
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'PORT';

11. This showed that the port was 3308 and not 3306 in my windows 10 machine
12. Changed the port in .env file
13. Again php artisan clear:cache
14. php artisan config:cache
15. Now gave the command- php artisan migrate:fresh --seed
16. Finally it was successful.

Answer (score 0):

None of the other answers worked for me. I solved the issue by simply adding a password to `DB_PASSWORD=` in `.env`, which was empty initially.